# DOT - how to reduce the lines connecting two nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a function that records the how methods are called at run-time. I am trying to use dot to visualize this information. Some methods are called many times- eg, in the case of a loop - in the graph i would want to have only one line connecting both nodes - Is there a switch do to this... See example diagram "RawFitsData._method" calls "RawFitsData.**init**"; multiple times, in the graph, i would like to display only one line[image]

```
digraph G{
    splines=false;
    ranksep=1;
node[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled];


    "DBProxy.fetch_from_database" -> "RawFitsData._method";
    "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__init__";
    "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__init__";
    "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__init__";
    "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__init__";
 "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__init__";
    "RawFitsData.__init__" -> "RawFitsData._method";
    "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__init__";
    "RawFitsData.__init__" -> "RawFitsData._set_pathname";
    "RawFitsData._set_pathname" ->"split";
    "RawFitsData._set_pathname" ->"setter";
    "RawFitsData.__init__" -> "RawFitsData._get_pathname";
    "RawFitsData._get_pathname" ->"getter";
    "RawFitsData._get_pathname" ->"join";
    "deepcopy" ->"RawFitsData._method";
    "RawFitsData._method" -> "RawFitsData.__reduce__";
    "RawFitsData.__reduce__" -> "WeakValueDictionary.__setitem__";
    "RawFitsData.__reduce__" ->"getter";
    "RawFitsData.__reduce__" -> "RawFitsData._get_pathname";
    "RawFitsData._get_pathname" ->"getter";

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use strict digraph.

```
strict digraph G {
    splines=false;
    ...
```

It will omit repeating edges. Reference: [DOT documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf).